# increment and decrement of a variable in printf

Tags: c

I wrote a simple program where `int a = 10` the o/p which i was expecting was `10 9 9`

```
 printf("a++:%d \t a:%d \t --a: %d \n", a++, a, --a);
```

but the o/p which is got is `9 10 10`

I wrote another printf like `printf(" a:%d \t --a: %d \n", a, --a);`

the o/p which i got is `9 9`

can anyone explain me about this ?

Comment: are you sure that u get 9 10 10 in the first printf ?

Comment: Other possible duplicates:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027347/c-function-parameter-evaluation-and-passing

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566187/function-parameter-evaluation-order

Comment: "can anyone explain me about this ?" -- if you want to know what the compiler did, that produced that result, then either disassemble the executable or else tell your compiler to output assembly. But in a fairly important sense it doesn't matter. Your code has undefined behavior per the standard, so "legally" the compiler could do anything. It's also likely to vary by compiler, version and optimization options.

Comment: yes i am, u can also check once for your cofirmation

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're experiencing *undefined behavior*, by having multiple expressions with side-effects, without [sequence points inbetween](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

There's no guarantee in which order function arguments are evaluated, so there's no way to "expect" something here (unless you wrote the compiler).

Comment: i wrote this printf as two separate instance

Comment: @Manu I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.